# Python Regular Expression Character following match does not equal

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a string if it starts with '123' but only if the immediate following character is not a numeric.

For example, these would match:

- '123'
- '123.4'
- '123A'

But these would not match:

- '124'
- '1234'
- '1235.3'

If I was only concerned with the string not ending with a numeric I could use:

```
'^123(?!.*\d$)'
```

However, this is NOT what I am looking for. I am looking for whether the character immediately following my match string is not a numeric.

Comment: You can use `^123(?!\d)`

Comment: This should also work `^123(?:\D|$)`

Comment: @anubhava oops you're right, I edited my previous comment!

Comment: @anubhava has two options that should cover you for the range of scenarios you have put in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for whether the character immediately following my match string is not a numeric.

You can use this regex:

```
^123(?!\d)
```

`(?!\d)` is negative lookahead that will assert failure if next character after `123` is a digit.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sWzD9t/1)

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's answer is correct, you can also use this which I think is simpler :

`^123\D{1}`

`\D` matches any non-digit character. 
you can replace `{1}` with any quantifier of your choice

Maybe you want to capture the full string, in that case you can modify :

`^123\D{1}.*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7vdnd1/2)